# Highmaps in yii using geojson file

Tags: yii, geojson, highmaps

I am using Yii Extension for high maps but unable to find an example of adding geojson file to it, yii extension provides following example and i want to add geojson file using php.

```
$this->widget('ext.highcharts.HighmapsWidget', array(
'options' => array(
    'title' => array(
        'text' => 'Highmaps basic demo',
    ),
    'series' => array(
        array(
            'data' => array(
                array('hc-key' => 'de-ni', 'value' => 0),
                array('hc-key' => 'de-hb', 'value' => 1),
            ),
            'mapData' => 'js:Highcharts.maps["countries/de/de-all"]',
            'joinBy' => 'hc-key',
            'name' => 'Random data',
        )
    )
)));
```

**'mapData' => 'js:Highcharts.maps["countries/de/de-all"]',**

your help will be highly appreciated,thanks

Comment: don't use link for code ...  but show your code in txt directly .. the use of link is deprecated  in SO and someone could downvote your question

Comment: how you obtain  the json data ?

Comment: I have the standard format what they need and its working in java script version of highmap but when loads direct link to highmap in extension show blank map !, I want to know how to add it in php version

Comment: i not asked for the format but. how you get this info in you php  code  .. you have an array?  .. you read a file?  .. show me this part of code .

Comment: ok, let make this easy how to implement [this](https://www.highcharts.com/maps/demo/geojson) example in [this](https://github.com/miloschuman/yii-highcharts/blob/master/doc/examples/highmaps.md) yii extension

Answer (score 0):

assuming you obtain the json files  using  file_get_contents

```
$json = file_get_contents('http://your.link.com');
```

and the json files is in the right format for you data

```
$yourJsonData = json_decode($json);
```

should be

```
......
'series' => array(
        array(
            'data' =>$yourJsonData,
            'mapData' => 'js:Highcharts.maps["countries/de/de-all"]',
            'joinBy' => 'hc-key',
            'name' => 'Random data',
        )
    )
....
```

Comment: Thanks for update, I am talking about **'mapData' => 'js:Highcharts.maps["countries/de/de-all"]'** as i have my own shapefiles and want to load, not data

Answer (score 0):

In case some one is still struggling with the same case, here is the trick. Use registerJs to attach your geojson file through myCallbackFunction at the end. All data will be reference through data variable in JS. Then use new JsExpression('data') to reference it at map key or mapData key. Below is sample code from my project

```
 $this->registerJs('$.getJSON("url_path_to_file.geojson", myCallbackFunction);');

 echo \miloschuman\highcharts\Highmaps::widget([
                            'callback' => 'myCallbackFunction',
                            'options' => [
                                'chart' => [
                                    'map' => new JsExpression('data'),
                                    'height' => 600
                                ],
                                'title' => ['text' => 'My Title'],
                                'colorAxis' => ['min' => 0],
                                'series' => [
                                    [
                                        //'mapData' => new JsExpression('data'),
                                        'data' => $map_data,
                                        'dataLabels' => ['enabled' => true, 'format' => '{point.name}'],
                                        'joinBy' => 'hc-key',
                                    ],
                                ],
                             
                            ]
                        ]);
```

Its explain in HighStock, with some edit of url it can work for map too. For reference https://github.com/miloschuman/yii2-highcharts/blob/master/doc/examples/highstock.md